# Accessor is not called

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I've a model named Order :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class Order extends Model
{
    public function getsystemIdAttribute()
    {
        return 99;
    }
    public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['createdAt'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    protected $fillable = ['customerId', 'itemId','systemId', 'createdAt'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

The problem is that the accessor - getsystemIdAttribute()suprise  isn't getting called, I tried it on other fields, however the accessor isn't called again.Of course I've changed the name form getsystemIdAttribute to getitemIdAttribute(for example). I copied the method on another model, and again changed the name a little bit and it worked. I fired up my debugger, and visited the view which is using this model, and to my surprise the method isn't getting called, but the fields from the database are returned. The version of Laravel is 5.3 and the database is MySQL, the version of php is 7. 
 Any idea what my be the problem.
EDIT: 
Here is the code in camel case:

```
public function getItemIdAttribute($value)
    {
        return 99;
    }
public function getSystemIdAttribute($value)
{
    return 99;
}
```

But again it isn't working, it's returning the data from the database.Here is the method which is retriving the data from the database:

```
 public function read_many($count, $page, $table){
        $tbl = Models::determine_table($table);
        return $tbl::skip(intval($count)*(intval($page)-1))->take(intval($count))->get()->toArray();
    }
```

Here is the determine_table method:

```
 public static $tables = [   'systems' => 'App\System',
                                'orders' => 'App\Order',
                                'notifiers' => 'App\Notifier',
                                'billings' => 'App\Billing',
                                'items' => 'App\Item',
                                'customers' => 'App\Customer',
                                'users' => 'App\User'
                            ];
    public static function determine_table($table_input){
        foreach(self::$tables as $table=>$class){
            if($table_input == $table){
                return $class;
            }
        }
        die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the method in studly case (as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators))!

So it would be `getSystemIdAttribute()` or `getItemIdAttribute()`

when you now execute `dd(Order::find(1)->system_id);` it should return 99 in case you have an Order object in the database.

**EDIT:** When using `toArray()`, mutators will not be executed! Check out [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/153#issuecomment-12820934) for a good explanation why it is intended like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the name doesn't work. I will update the question, and post the code.

Comment: Tried, didn't work. The data is again the one from the database.

Comment: How do you retrieve the data?

Comment: The dd returned, the expected value. In a second I will post the controller method in the question

Comment: Updated my answer. The toArray() function is the "problem" here.